# Ruby Selenium, can find_elements return an array with elements and nil?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I didn't think that find_elements would return an array with elements and `nil`. Look at what I'm looking at in IRB.

```
irb(main):025:0>  w = $driver.find_elements(:tag_name, 'tr')
=> [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x77dbee53bb7dc76a id="{2cea6188-1aa3-9045-acbc-c4e7e6b789ee}">, #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x1000c5ad74eacaee id="{79c30952-9be5-3e4e-be0d-1f8c527541ff}">]
irb(main):026:0> w[1]
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x1000c5ad74eacaee id="{79c30952-9be5-3e4e-be0d-1f8c527541ff}">
irb(main):027:0> w[2]
=> nil
```

What is going on?  Bug in Selenium or bug in Ruby?
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
selenium-webdriver 2.39.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w = $driver.find_elements(:tag_name, 'tr')` gives you an `Array`.

> [In Ruby Array indexing starts at 0](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html), as in C or Java. A negative index is assumed to be relative to the end of the array---that is, an index of -1 indicates the last element of the array, -2 is the next to last element in the array, and so on.

So in your case `w` is a sized *2* array. `w[0]` will give you first and `w[1]` will second element, and there is no element at index `2`,`3`,`4` and so on.. So every attempt to those index will give you `nil` element.

Comment: Wow I knew that, guess its going to be a rough Monday morning.