# RSpec: Cant Verify there are more than 5 Btns on Search Result Page

Tags: selenium, rspec

I try to do an Selenium-Acceptancetest 'Search Result List' with `RSpec spec`

- And my Issue is
  It should verify the count of a Button "Detail"

I would be happy to get help for start thinking as a coder; i am a manual tester stil.

My Problem now is:

```
Method Error
Failure/Error: expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").to be > 4)

NoMethodError:
undefined method `to' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x00000003fd4938>
```

- Sources:
  On my way to resolve the issue I tried to modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present) and I found [this](http://ttps://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers)
  But its not working

thanksfully remaining!

my Test File:

```
# coding: utf-8
puts "this is #{File.basename(__FILE__)}"
extend RSpec::Expectations
extend RSpec::Matchers

describe 'SEL' do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = loadDriver()        
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
  end

  it 'test_Page (SEL)' do
    #get the page
    ...
    #do input keyword 'Restaurant'
    ...
    #click submit
    ...
    #(Works!) temp Validation1: Is there a "Btn Details" in SearchResultList?
    expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").displayed?)
    #(Works not!) Validation: Are there more than "5 Btns Detail"
    expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").to be > 5)
  end
end
```

---

**Update after first answer:**

Given I use

```
expect(@driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]")).to be > 0
```

it hits that error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]")).to be > 0

expected: > 0
got:   [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0xa6219008 id="a2a2c83a-e52d-4464-81ec-4fce07ccc0b6">, #<Selenium::We...64378279">, #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f90cc8d0e id="de990e21-eecf-48db-873b-76515dba7c3e">]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message:

```
undefined method `to' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x00000003fd4938>
```

I suspect your issue is a missing bracket.  Normal Rspec syntax is

```
expect(something).to eq(some value).
```

I would imagine you are missing the closing parenthesis

```
expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").to be > 5)
```

and this should be something more like:

```
expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]")).to be > 5
```

Although I might guess you need to call a size function on the latter part as well as maybe use [find elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534283/ruby-selenium-can-find-elements-return-an-array-with-elements-and-nil).  Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244041/ruby-selenium-web-driver-how-to-count-child-element-nodes-of-a-specific-node) will also be useful for you.

Comment: funny:
if I use yours happens.. I should update my Question.

Comment: @Webdriver you're still missing a component of the answer - you'll need to use a size function.  You're still comparing a collection of elements to a number (in the links they use .length).